# How to Get the title in share extension view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-share-extension

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems[0];
    NSItemProvider *itemProvider = item.attachments[0];
     NSLog(@"%@",itemProvider);

    if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePlainText])
    {    
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePlainText options:nil completionHandler:^(NSString *item, NSError *error)
        {       
            if (item)
            {
                textString=item;    
            }
        }];
    }
```

I am using share extension in my app. I am using it as a subclass of a UIViewController not SLcomposer.In the viewDidLoad i am trying to access the text in the page from `NSItemProvider`,But it has only one key which is public url , Can anybody give me an idea of how to achieve the `kUTTypePlainText` in  `NSItemProvider`. I also set  NSExtensionActivationSupportsText, its type to Boolean, and the value to YES

Answer (score 7):

You can use the ExtensionPreprocessingJS to do this.

First, add the the `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` key to the `NSExtensionAttributes` dictionary in your Info.plist. The value should be the name of your JavaScript file without the extension, i.e. `MyExtensionJavaScriptClass`.

Then, in the `NSExtensionActivationRule` dictionary in your Info.plist, set the `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount` key with a value of 1 (type Number).

Next, add `MyExtensionJavaScriptClass.js` to your extension with the following code:

```
var MyExtensionJavaScriptClass = function() {};

MyExtensionJavaScriptClass.prototype = {
    run: function(arguments) {
       arguments.completionFunction({"title": document.title});
    } 
};

// The JavaScript file must contain a global object named "ExtensionPreprocessingJS".
var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new MyExtensionJavaScriptClass;
```

Then include the following function in your ShareViewController `viewDidLoad` and `import MobileCoreServices`

```
    let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as! NSExtensionItem
    let itemProvider = extensionItem.attachments?.first as! NSItemProvider

    let propertyList = String(kUTTypePropertyList)
    if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(propertyList) {
        itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(propertyList, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) -> Void in
            let dictionary = item as! NSDictionary
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                let results = dictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey] as! NSDictionary
                let title = results["title"] as! String                                        
                //yay, you got the title now
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've to request the site using the provided URL, parse the content  and get the title from that string.

BTW: Apple Documentation say:

> If your Share or iOS Action extension needs to access a webpage, you must include the NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount key with a nonzero value

See the section "[Accessing a Webpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW12)"